# What rank of admiral was Picard at the time of his retirement?

Tags: star-trek, jean-luc-picard, star-trek-picard

What this referenced in the *Star Trek: Picard*  or the Countdown comic?   Or can we tell from his 2485 uniform?

Answer (score 21):

I believe he had four pips inside a rectangular bar. That makes him an **admiral** which matches all the references I've seen; e.g. [Admiral Jean-Luc Picard, Retired](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard)¹.

[image]    [image]
    <sub>First image is a screenshot from the flashback scene in ST-PIC S01E03 '[The End is the Beginning](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_End_is_the_Beginning_(episode))' immediately following Starfleet's acceptance of Admiral Picard's resignation with his rank insignia showing the four-pips-in-a-bar of a flag officer admiral. Second image is an image detailing Starfleet commissioned officer ranks and associated insignias. Click for larger image(s).</sub>

[image]
<sub>Additional screen capture from *Star Trek: Picard* e1s03 "The End is the Beginning". (thanks are due to ThePopMachine)</sub>

As an Admiral, he was one rank below Fleet Admiral (5 pips inside bar), and above Vice Admiral (3 pips inside bar), Rear Admiral Upper Half (2 pips inside bar) and Rear Admiral Lower Half (1 pip inside bar)².

These pips parallel the stars accorded the admiralty ranks within the US Navy.

FWIW, the rectangular bar surrounding admiralty rank in Starfleet always reminded me of the rectangle with rounded corners encompassing an Egyption pharaoh's [cartouche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartouche). The cartouche's surrounding border has been interpreted by modern scholars as a means to protect the pharaoh from evil spirits in life and after death.

---

¹ <sub>Memory Alpha lists Jean-Luc Picard as one of the individuals who attained the flag officer grade of [admiral](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Admiral#Starfleet) in Starfleet. Inclusion in these Starfleet lists is typically made only at the highest rank that an individual has attained; e.g. Picard is not listed in all the ranks he attained up to flag officer admiral, only flag officer admiral.</sub>

² <sub>[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Portal:Main) has done a pretty good job of providing information pages for [Starfleet ranks](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_ranks) and [flag officers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Flag_officer). There are individual information pages for the Admiralty ([Fleet Admiral](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fleet_admiral), [Admiral](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Admiral), [Vice Admiral](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vice_admiral) and [Rear Admiral (Upper and Lower)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rear_admiral) in addition to others.</sub>

Comment: [There are five *pips*. How many do you see now?](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chain_of_Command,_Part_II_(episode))

Comment: What's the source for the image?

Comment: Yes, what's the source of this image?  It's hard to accept this answer without knowing this.

Comment: While fixing that, you might also address how "click for larger image" does not actually give a larger image.  If you want to go full Buzzfeed, make it show the thumbnail :)

Comment: [here](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/9/98/Picard_and_Raffi%2C_2385.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20200210164554&path-prefix=en) is a nice picture of the four pips in a rectangle from Episode 3 of ST: P.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer - Thanks for that! I've fixed the image problem and provided a source but please leave the link to yours available

Comment: that's a turrible photoshop job in that picture. No way on earth it's legit

Comment: Isn't the "Fleet Admiral" a unique position?  As in, there's only one at any given time, kind of like the Joint Chiefs of the US military branches.  So Picard reached the highest rank one can possibly achieve without actually being *the* Fleet Admiral.

Comment: Here, I did an actual screen get grab for you.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Yes and no. There was some ret-conning with ST-TOS admiralty insignias largely due to explaining a commodore or ambassador or something having fleet admiral rank. It's all a bit confusing.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - *'In Starfleet, fleet admiral existed as a separate rank, but was also used as a title awarded and referring to officers wearing insignia of vice admiral or admiral, such as Fleet Admiral Shanthi. (TNG: "Redemption II") In these situations when an officer referred to an admiral as "fleet admiral" they could simply have been calling them fleet admiral because they were acting as the head of a fleet. Field promotion is another possibility.'* ([source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fleet_admiral))

Comment: @Jeeped:   No need to keep it if you think it's now redundant.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I believe the art director chose to shoot in the shade of the trees to add some gloom to this solemn moment. While I approve of the result, it makes getting a decent screen grab of uniform details like rank decoration pretty tough. So the more the merrier and again, thanks.

Comment: @Daniel Hoffman: in the US military the five-star ranks - Fleet Admiral and General of the Army - have not been awarded since WWII. The only Fleet Admirals were Leahy, King, Halsey, and Nimitz. In the army the only five-star generals were Eisenhower, Marshall, MacArthur, Arnold, and Bradley.

Comment: In the US military are the five-star ranks only awarded during times of war?

Comment: This is interesting! I thought he was a lower ranked admiral. This makes me frown upon FAdm. Clancy for not letting Picard have a warp capable ship with a crew since he was just a rank below her.

Comment: @HunterBatley Picard was a retired veteran sure, but a *civilian* at that point, not "a rank below her".

Comment: @T.J.L. Please notice the use of "was" in my comment.

Comment: @HunterBatley Please notice the use of "at that point" in my comment. Why would Clancy do anything for him? He was disgraced *and* a civilian. His prior rank is precisely irrelevant when he's effectively *persona non grata*.

Comment: @T.J.L. You misinterpreted my comment. I meant that he was a rank below her when he was an admiral. I understand that he's a civilian and disgraced (perhaps wrongly depending on how you define wrong in this context) in the show; however, given Picard's service to the Federation before the Romulus incident (and even an appeal based on Data's service to the Federation), one *might* expect some leniency. Also, I would say it's hard to turn away from people you've served with in the past.

Comment: Take the attitude of Captian Sulu in VOY:"Flashback". SULU: There is a sense of loyalty to the men and women you serve with. A sense of family. Those two men on trial, I served with them for a long time. I owe them my life a dozen times over, and right now they're in trouble, and I'm going to help them. Let the regulations be damned.

Comment: @HunterBatley Using Sulu's personal feelings for Kirk and McCoy as an argument to support a conclusion on Picard and Clancy's relationship is quite a stretch. There's no evidence that Clancy and Picard ever served together - she just happens to be the commander-in-chief at the time he needed a favor. Unfortunately for him, she appears to be a bit of a Federation isolationist, and also believes he's arrogant: "We had to make choices, but the great Captain Picard didn't like his orders."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106761/discussion-between-hunter-batley-and-t-j-l).

Answer (score 0):

A four pip admiral is a rank. A five pip is an award like a citation. The award is often given for political reasons. So it makes sense that Clancy would be 5 and Picard would be 4. Four pip can be the cammander and Chief of the entire fleet.